# Updating HTML File No Domain Name

Tags: html, dns

I have an HTML file that I gave to a couple of friends. I want to update the file, and want them to see the update, but I don't want to give them each the file again, and again (every time I make an update). Besides making it public with a domain name, what else can I do?

Comment: Not really a programming question. A standard file sharing application like Dropbox would help you here.

Comment: @MattJ: But wouldn't I still have to upload the new edits to Dropbox?

Comment: Dropbox automatically synchronises when you change the file. Your friends can either install Dropbox to have the file automatically update on their system too when you change it, or you can use Dropbox to share a URL to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making it private "with a domain name" (meaning hosting it on a web-site)? Just post it on the site and put a password on the directory, and tell your friends the password.

I'm assuming your issue is with the public aspect, not hosting it on a web site per se.

If you don't want the trouble of setting up a website, just setup a gMail account and upload it to Google Documents and share it there with only the people you want to see it.

Comment: You've assumed correctly. I never thought of that. But how would I go about making the password?

Comment: It depends on where you are hosting it. Usually you can just turn off anonymous access to the directory in question and it will prompt for credentials.